# how to blit a function to screen after keydown event (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

i am trying to make my screen switch from the intro screen to an instructions screen by pressing a space bar. However, when you press the space bar, the instructions screen only stays on as you press it

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    intro_screen()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            instructions()
            pygame.display.flip()
```

how do i fix this to last on the screen? also, is it possible i can use the same key to display different functions?

I am a pygame newbie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code needs to maintain the state of the display.  Currently the main loop seems to *always* draw the "Intro Screen", and, as you say, only draw the "Instructions Screen" on spacebar-event.  Also this is put into the event handler code, it probably should be outside that part.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    intro_screen()                               # <-- Draw intro
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            instructions()                       # <-- Draw Instructions
        pygame.display.flip()
```

It's better to store which screen to show in a variable.

```
current_screen = 'introduction'              # enumerated type would be better
done = False

# main loop
while not done:
    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN ):
            if ( event.key == pygame.K_SPACE ):
                current_screen = 'instructions'    # switch screens
            elif ( event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE ):
                current_screen = 'introduction'    # switch screens back

    # paint the screen
    if ( current_screen = 'introduction' ):
        intro_screen()                             # draw the introduction screen
    elif ( current_screen = 'instructions' ):
        instructions()                             # draw the instructions
    else:
        # TODO - more screen types
        pass

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was great.

Comment: Glad I could help!